# How to use top statement inside the sql function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to use top statement inside the sql function
But got a red underline under the TOP, saing that **incorrect syntax near the TOP**

[image]

Comment: Please don't post code as image, use the formatting functions in the editor and post it as text. Also, please keep in mind, that Stack Overflow is not a debugger service, please do your own research first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
SELECT TOP 1 @SelectedTableName = t.Name
FROM #temp t
WHERE t.IsSlected = 0
```

OR

```
SET @SelectedTableName = (SELECT TOP 1 @SelectedTableName = t.Name
                          FROM #temp t
                          WHERE t.IsSlected = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

A Variable (Except Table Variable) Can store only one value at a time, so even if you don't specify the `TOP 1`, it will only take the TOP value by default, otherwise if you want to select some intermediate value, then You might have to sepcify some `order by` Clause.

Here you can just use this

```
SELECT @SelectedTableName = t.Name
FROM #temp t
WHERE t.IsSlected = 0
```